# CRM PlugIn Pass Variable Flag to New Execution Pipeline

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011

I have records that have an index attribute to maintain their position in relation to each other.

I have a plugin that performs a renumbering operation on these records when the index is changed or new one created. There are specific rules that apply to items that are at the first and last position in the list.

If a new (or existing changed) item is inserted into the middle (not technically the middle...just somewhere between start and end) of the list a renumbering kicks off to make room for the record.

This renumbering process fires in a new execution pipeline...We are updating record D. When I tell record E to change (to make room for D) that of course fires the plugin on update message.

This renumbering is fine until we reach the end of the list where the plugin then gets into a loop with the first business rule that maintains the first and last record differently.

So I am trying to think of ways to pass a flag to the execution context spawned by the renumbering process so the recursion skips the boundary edge business rules if IsRenumbering == true.

**My thoughts / ideas:**

I have thought of using the Depth check > 1 but that isn't a reliable value as I can't explicitly turn it on or off....it may happen to work but that is not engineering a solid solution that is hoping nothing goes bump. Further a colleague far more knowledgeable than I said that when a workflow calls a plugin the depth value is off and can't be trusted.

---

All my variables are scoped at the execute level so as to avoid variable pollution at the class level....However if I had a dictionary object, tuple, something at the class level and one value would be the thread id and the other the flag value then perhaps my subsequent execution context could check if the same owning thread id had any values entered.

---

Any thoughts or other ideas on how to pass context information to a new pipeline would be greatly appreciated.

---

Per Nicknow sugestion I tried sharedvariables but they seem to be going out of scope...:

First time firing post op:

```
if (base.Stage == EXrmPluginStepStage.PostOperation)
{
 ...snip...

    foreach (var item in RenumberSet)
    {
       Context.ParentContext.SharedVariables[recordrenumbering] = "googly";

       Entity renumrec = new Entity("abcd") { Id = item.Id };

          #region We either add or subtract indexes based upon sortdir
               ...snip...
               renumrec["abc_indexfield"] = TmpIdx + 1;
               break;
               .....snip.....
          #endregion

         OrganizationService.Update(renumrec);
      }

}
```

Now we come into Pre-Op of the recursion process kicked off by the above post-op OrganizationService.Update(renumrec); and it seems based upon this check the sharedvariable didn't carry over...???

```
 if (!Context.SharedVariables.Contains(recordrenumbering))
 {
   //Trace.Trace("Null Set");
   //Context.SharedVariables[recordrenumbering] = IsRenumbering;
   Context.SharedVariables[recordrenumbering] = "Null Set";
 }
```

throw invalidpluginexception reveals:

```
 Sanity Checks:
    Depth : 2
    Entity: ...
    Message: Update
    Stage: PreOperation [20]
    User: 065507fe-86df-e311-95fe-00155d050605
    Initiating User: 065507fe-86df-e311-95fe-00155d050605
ContextEntityName: ....
ContextParentEntityName: ....
....
IsRenumbering: Null Set
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is [`IExecutionContext.SharedVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iexecutioncontext.sharedvariables.aspx). Whatever you add here is available throughout the entire transaction. Since you'll have child pipelines you'll want to look at the `ParentContext` for the value. This can all get a little tricky, so be sure to do a lot of testing - I've run into many issues with `SharedVariables` and looping operations in Dynamics CRM.

Here is some sample (very untested) code to get you started.

```
    public static bool GetIsRenumbering(IPluginExecutionContext pluginContext)
    {
        var keyName = "IsRenumbering";
        var ctx = pluginContext;

        while (ctx != null)
        {
            if (ctx.SharedVariables.Contains(keyName))
            {
                return (bool)ctx.SharedVariables[keyName];
            }
            else ctx = ctx.ParentContext;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void SetIsRenumbering(IPluginExecutionContext pluginContext)
    {
        var keyName = "IsRenumbering";
        var ctx = pluginContext;

        ctx.SharedVariables.Add(keyName, true);
    }
```

Comment: I thought shared variables would go out of scope when the recursion fires...it is the recursion firing that needs to read the IsRenumbering flag...but it seems from your answer that I am wrong about this so I will explore what you have presented. Thank You!

Comment: see my edits please. Perhaps I am not understanding the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution: add a bit field to the entity called "DisableIndexRecalculation." When your first plugin runs, make sure to set that field to true for all of your updates. In the same plugin, check to see if "DisableIndexRecalculation" is set to true: if so, set it to null (by removing it from the TargetEntity entirely) and stop executing the plugin. If it is null, do your index recalculation.

Because you are immediately removing the field from the TargetEntity if it is true the value will never be persisted to the database so there will be no performance penalty.

Comment: When you say in the same plugin...(" In the same plugin, check to see if "DisableIndexRecalculation" is set to true") do you mean in the recursion pre-op process or still in the post op of the first time through?

Comment: You'll have one plugin registered for the PreCreate/PreUpdate stage. It first checks to see if it should suppress index recalculation (DisableIndexRecalcuation = true). If so, it also removes the DisableIndexRecalculation field from the TargetEntity so it won't be persisted to the db. Otherwise, it recalculates the index. The end result is that you can create a record "in the middle" and that plugin will update all of its siblings' indices while carefully setting DisableIndexRecalcuation on each of those updates so the siblings' plugin execution won't also fire the index recalculation.